# Is there any difference between using &#010; and &#10; in xml?

Tags: xml, dtd

I was using a web-service which accepts xml input, but when i use `&#010;` for new line it is rejecting the input saying dtd validation error. But when i use `&#10;` it is accepting. But from docs of web-service i see that they suggest us to use `&#010;`.

Which is the correct format?

Comment: `from xml docs i see that we should use &#010;` - Can you link to these documents?

Comment: Which document says that you *should* use `&#010;`?

Comment: It is according to the web service docs, i am not sure i can share it here. But i basically wanted to understand the standard and correct format to use.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are the same. The numbers after the `&#` is the codepoint and can be specified in decimal form  (as in your case) with or without leading zeroes, or in hexadecimal form `&#xNNNN`.

Read more about [Character and Entity References](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references).